# Minimize search box with ESC

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, search, keyboard-shortcuts

A tiny cosmetic feature request:

Could the search box be minimized with a press on Escape? Now we have to click somewhere outside the search box to minimize it to its initial size in order to get access to the header/top menu. Doing so with ESC would save a click.

Comment: +1 that would be helpful...and intuitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, this sounds like reasonable enough behavior.

This change will go out in the next build:  hitting escape will de-focus and collapse the search box.